# single-variate function variational Intensity Plot for Matlab

Tags: matlab, plotting

I'm wondering if it's possible to create functional intensity plots in matlab. Examples of what I'm looking for are below found in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10618-014-0371-0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

These figures were (guessing) probably made in R, but is this possible for matlab? I can't seem to find anything related to intensity besides an *image* intensity plot.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I think I found the closest thing to what I really wanted:

[image]

which is from [here](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/timeseries_bootstrapped.html#timeseries-bootstrapped).

This is the `seaborn` library in python, which seems to act mostly as an extension to matplotlib and pyplot. My OP seems to be a variation on this library plotting function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking for can be found in this package, patchline.m, available from Matlab Central.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline/content/patchline.m

Please note the basic usage as is outlined in

```
help patchline

%Example 
t = 0:pi/64:4*pi;
p = patchline(t,sin(t),'edgecolor','b','linewidth',2,'edgealpha',.05);
```

'edgecolor' and 'linewidth' correspond to their obvious graphical properties, but what you may be unfamiliar with is the 'edgealpha' (valued between 0 and 1) which will determine the transparency of the lines which you are plotting.